# Powershell to fetch software's license key?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to fetch details about Softwares that are installed on my machine using Powershell. I am able to get all the details I need using the below mentioned command:

```
$details = get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*
```

However, as a part of new requirement I would also like to get software's license key. I see there are Softwares who are able to fetch license key for any installed software, but still not sure how to get any Software's license key using Powershell. 
I tried this but the results are not what I want:

```
(Get-WmiObject -query ‘select * from SoftwareLicensingService’)
```

Any leads will be helpful.

Comment: This will vary greatly depending on the target software - whether it's in the registry, on disk, encrypted, or hashed, or any number of other possibilities including not actually being there at all.

Comment: I would like to get the license key of any software that is installed and in turn is listed in HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

Comment: Indeed.  As alluded to in my first comment, there is no central store of such information - it's entirely down to each bit of software how it handles it - you'd need to write a module for each individual application to get hold of it, if you even can.

Comment: Doesn't make sense then. I guess using a software to fetch such details would make sense.

Comment: An actual piece of software will still have the same limitations as your powershell scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single mechanism to store license information in Windows. As such, every application rolls their own. Some store it in files, some in the registry, some in more obscure ways.

Not even the details of what *is* license information (a key? a name/password pair? A guid? An encryption secret?) is uniform across applications.

So there is no way to read license information. If you found a software that "does it", it just means they implemented a huge list of programs, licence information and ways to find them on a windows machine.